# getting res.flush is not a function in express-sse

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

I am trying to use express-sse to generate a notification and call the api automatically when an order is placed.

Here is my API:

```
router.post("/createOrder", async (req, res) => {
    try {
        let { orderItems, email, orderStatus, paymentStatus, orderType, orderAmount, tableId } = req.body

        const order = await Order.create({
            orderItems, email, orderStatus, paymentStatus, orderType, orderAmount
        });
        await Table.updateOne({ tableId: tableId },
            {
                $set: {
                    currentOrders: { $push: { orderItems, email, orderStatus, paymentStatus, orderType, orderAmount } },
                    status: 'occupied'
                }
            })
        sse.send(order, "order_created");

        res.status(200).json({ message: "Order Placed" })

    } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).json("Server Error!")
        console.log(err);
    }
});
```

the server crashes with error res.flush is not a function.

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uo7Y8.png)

I tried sending the sse after res.status(). It works and I get the response at me sse stream endpoint [SSE stream response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HsBSZ.png) but then the call gets closed in postman and I get error: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client.

[headers error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RG6wa.png)

Comment: Probably your version of `express` and `express-sse` aren't compatible. You can try `express-sse@0.5.2`, according to commits history this version hasn't a call to `flush()`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that express-sse uses the flush() method, which was deprecated.
There are a couple of workarounds you can try:

1. Implement a middleware with a dummy flush method:

   ```
   app.get('/sse', (req, res, next) => {
     res.flush = () => {}; 
     next();
   }, sse.init);
   ```
2. Use the compression middleware, which provides a flush method:
   First install the compression package:

   ```
   npm install compression
   ```

   Then, implement the middleware in your app before using sse.init:

   ```
   const express = require('express');
   const compression = require('compression');
   const SSE = require('express-sse');
   //...
   const sse = new SSE();
   const app = express();
   app.use(compression());
   app.get('/sse', sse.init);
   ```

For more information on the deprecation of the flush method, refer to the [Node.js API deprecations page](https://nodejs.org/api/deprecations.html#DEP0001). Additionally, you can find discussions and additional context in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/dpskvn/express-sse/issues/28).